# MS Word Integration in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have tried to look around for documentation on this subject, but I haven't really found a concrete answer. Just answers to problems that I am not really facing.

I want to pull some patterns and phrases from a database and generate a docx (or doc?) file in MS Word using C#. It's part of a school project. But the integration part doesn't seem to be very well documented, or I am looking in the wrong places.

Any help with this?

Comment: Actually, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10412/2065121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic word for google purposes is "Interop".  Try this as a starting point:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/word

Comment: Thanks dude. What a weird name. Interop.

Comment: You're welcome.  MS Word is not always the best way of making a document from C# though.  Check out this answer for a good overview: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10423

Comment: The thing is that the requirements says MS Word. So have to use it, like it or not ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to create word documents programmatically:

- Create the documents by calling (and starting) word programmatically
- Create the word document in the open XML format readable by Word.

For more info see similar questions here on stackoverflow:
[How to create word docs programmatically from a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304238/how-to-create-word-docs-programmatically-from-a-template)

Answer (score 0):

Try use Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)

It provides easy way to work with docx file.
After words docx format is simple zipped xml file.