# C# Word Interop cannot Add document

Tags: c#, office-interop

I try to add a document from template with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, using:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Aplication wordApp = 
             new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

wordApp.Documents.Add("somedoc.dotx");
```

But I always get an unhandled `COMException`, telling me the file might be damaged. I tried `doc`, `docx` and `dotx` and I am sure the file exists, because I check it before. When I open the file in Word, it opens fine.

Comment: First argument is the *template*.  "somedoc.docx" does not sound much like a template although we never seem to be able to rely on valid code snippets at SO.  Oh joy.  Consider passing no arguments at all, you don't name the file until you save it.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried actual templates as well (as it stated in my question). And I do need to use the file as template, I clarified my question a little.

Comment: A related question is [How to create word docs programmatically from a template](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4304238/4519059) ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, `Add()` wants a full path:

```
wordApp.Documents.Add(Path.GetFullPath("somedoc.docx"));
```

works fine, with both `docx` and `dotx` files.

Comment: I ran into this same issue a while back, very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Add()` to add a new file, and `.Open()` to open an existing file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.aspx

Comment: I want to create a new file, based on an existing one. `docx` is used as a template here. Basically the only difference between `docx` and `dotx` is Word's behaviour when opening it. For interop this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I haven't worked with these for a while, but if I recall correctly the documents themselves aren't any different either, from a file structure standpoint.  I suspect that you won't have success with trying to use the `.Add()` method on an existing document either way.